# How to open a new tab in a chrome extension and show data

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which allows the user to perform actions and build up data. How can I get my chrome extension to open a new tab to allow my user to interact with the data they've accumulated? I could build a separate web app service where I pass the users data to. I currently persist the users data in local storage but I want a way for them to view/edit that data.

Not sure what exactly to google to get a chrome extensions to launch a new page under it's url...

Edit:

Ideally I'd like for my user to press a button from the popup.html popup to open up the new tab, if possible.

Comment: You need the [tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs).

Answer (score 5):

I got it to work, basically from the popup.html page I can make this javascript call,

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL('dashboard.html')})
```

where 'dashboard.html' is file belonging to my chrome extension.